# Changing the Name of PC

Tags: hostname

Will I have any **conflicts** in my computer file manager system if change the name of my PC to another name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. Anything in your system will pick up the new name.

In case anyone wonders see ...

```
/etc/hostname
/etc/hosts
```